# changing X-UA-Compatible meta tag with javascript based on iframe url

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

context:

I am working on a large site with some old controls that break in newer browsers so we have had to force IE7 document mode with your standard meta X-UA-Compatible tag. We have replaced most of the problem controls but do not have the time and budget to replace them all. We would like to have the pages that dont have the controls to render in the current document mode for IE browsers to take advantage of the client side performance boosts that that provides. The problem is that I am having trouble getting that the newer ie browsers to switch modes like i want. The navigation of the site uses an iframe which i feel is probably my main issue. I have my javascript on the parent page with the iframe.

I would like to be able to do this with javascript, and have been attempting to do so. Here is what I am doing. It successfuly changes the Tag, but the browser doesnt seem to care. **What do I need to change in order for the browsers to consider the Tags?**

```
     //tag swapping code 
     function FixIEMetaTag(url) {

         //Remove current IE meta Tag
         var iefixTagOld = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];
         if (iefixTagOld) { iefixTagOld.parentNode.removeChild(iefixTagOld); }

         //Determine Document Type for IE browsers
         var contentVal = 'IE=Edge';             
         if (IsPageWithBadGrid(url)) { contentVal = 'IE=7'; }

         //Create and add new IE meta Tag
         var iefixTag = document.createElement('meta');
         iefixTag.setAttribute("http-equiv", "X-UA-Compatible");
         iefixTag.setAttribute("content", contentVal);
         var theHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         theHead.insertBefore(iefixTag, theHead.firstChild);
     }

     //navigation code
     function GoToPage(url) {

         if (window.frames["ifrm"]) {

             FixIEMetaTag(url);

             window.open(url,"ifrm");
             return false;
         }

         return true;
     }
```

Comment: There's no use to change `<meta>`s programmatically after the page has been loaded. They are executed while loading, and adding / changing / removing `<meta>`s is ignored afterwards.

Comment: I was hoping there was some sort of way to yell at the browser to do something when it loaded the iframe content, but i guess not

Comment: Well, `iframe`s might be even more difficult target for setting document mode in IE. They usually inherit the mode from the main window, and even literal `x-ua-compatible` is ignored, especially when trying to use "higher" mode in the `iframe`.

Comment: Why does your nav need to be in an i-frame? Is it difficult to move that out?

Comment: @ErikReppen the content is in the iframe. and some content needs the browser to load in ie7 doc mode.

Answer (score 2):

To be effective, the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag must be present when the page is loaded. By the time that Javascript runs, it's too late to change.

If you really need to switch IE7 mode on and off for the content of an iframe, your best bet is to keep two versions of the page with different `X-UA-Compatible` tags, or to pass the compatibility flag in via a URL parameter (e.g, `?mode=ie7` vs. `?mode=edge`).

Comment: so pretty much, i need to reload the parent page? I was trying to get around doing that because this one does so much crap on load with the assumption that it wont be reloaded.

Comment: @Teemu I'm thinking he is suggesting something along the lines of what I put in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just as a thought of what i should do based on the answers and comments so far...

It sounds as if i need to reload the main page to change the IE meta tag. Based on my current code im thinking something like this:

```
 //navigation code
 function GoToPage(url) {

     if (window.frames["ifrm"]) {

         var oldContentTagValue = 'IE=Edge';  
         //Determine Previous IEType tag
         var iefixTagOld = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];
         if (iefixTagOld) { 
             oldContentTagValue = (?);//something fancy to get current tag type

         }

         //Determine Document Type for IE browsers
         var contentVal = 'IE=Edge';             
         if (IsPageWithBadGrid(url)) { contentVal = 'IE=7'; }

         if(oldContentTagValue !=contentVal ){
             //redirect to current page with contenttypetag stuff and iframe url in query string
         }
         else{
             window.open(url,"ifrm");
         }
         return false;
     }

     return true;
 }
```

And then i would set the iframe url and correct meta tag on load, based on the query string params... Thoughts?

Comment: `"something fancy"` is `oldContentTagValue = iefixTagOld.content` (_if_ the first `meta`really is `x-ua compatible`). But beware, `<meta>`s are not case-sensitive, so it's better to convert the value to upper/lower case before comparing...

Comment: To catch the `x-ua compatible` you could iterate through all `<meta>`s, and check the value of `.httpEquiv` of each tag, until `x-ua compatible` is found (remembering case-insensitivity).