# Override meta tag with a new meta tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a asp page and I would like to override "meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"" with "meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"" in one of the pages using JavaScript. Is it possible? I have tried the following with no success.

```
    window.onload = function(e){ 
    $('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">')
}
```

Comment: Or instead of removing you can just use `attr` function like `.attr("content","IE=10")`

Comment: @Manjunath: I tried doing attr function like $('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]').attr('content','IE=10'); and it still did not work

Comment: Can you tell us Where and how are you including this scripts?

Comment: This will not work because by the time `window.onload` is fired, the meta tag is already read, the compatibility flag set, and the document parsed in that mode. This needs to be changed on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing X-UA-Compatible meta tag with javascript based on iframe url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900084/changing-x-ua-compatible-meta-tag-with-javascript-based-on-iframe-url)

Comment: @Manjunath:  I am including the script on the page that I am working on As Heretic has mentioned, it will not work do to the explanation given.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible, but you need to call `.remove()` (missed the `()`)

although I'm not sure what you wish to accomplish will actually work (if you want to make IE behave differently)

Comment: I realize that and I added the missing "()". However, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

**jQuery**

```
if (window.location.pathname === 'myPage') { // URL is example.com/myPage
    $('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]').replaceWith('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">'); 
}
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
if (window.location.pathname === 'myPage') { // URL is example.com/myPage
    document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]').outerHTML = '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">';
}
```

Comment: @user9808783 what exactly is not working? Do you get an error message? Does it work without the if statement?

Comment: @ Reza: By not working, what I mean is the meta tag that contains content="IE=8" is not being replace with "IE=10"

Comment: @user9808783 I have tested it on JSFiddle and it works for me.  https://jsfiddle.net/RezaScript/2ozpc9t8/

Comment: @ Reza:  I see you are using Jquery 3.3.1. Unfortunately, I am using 1.6.1. Is there an approach in that version

Comment: I have also tried the attr(), if I am reading the documentation correctly for 1.6.1, but it also did not work

Comment: @user9808783 no, that cannot be the reason, since the function `replaceWith()` exists since the version 1.2. But you could also try it with pure JavaScript. I have updated my answer. It's tested and it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put your answer in $(document).ready(). Since you're using jQuery you can do:

```
$(function() {
    $('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">');
});
```

Here is a good explanation on the difference between `window.onload` and `$(document).ready()`:
[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)